# Method Variable to Class Variable

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, pagination, xamarin

I have declared a variable for my class called `FLDTRequest.cs` called

`Pagination instagramPagination;`

In my method to request JSON from the Instagram website I have made it so that it equals the class variable `instagramPagination`.

**Get Instagram Feed Method**

```
var client = new RestClient ("https://api.instagram.com/v1");
        client.ExecuteAsync (request, response => {
            var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject> (response.Content);
        table.InvokeOnMainThread (() => {
            // Create list that contains newly attained JSON
            List<Datum> instagramData = rootObject.data;
            // Make the local Variable for Pagination equal the Class Variable           
            instagramPagination = rootObject.pagination;
            table.ReloadData ();
        });
    });
```

However when I try to use this `instagramPagination` variable after the **Get Instagram Feed** Method is called it says that the Object reference is not set to an instance of an object.

Here is the method which I am using the `instagramPagination` variable.

**Get Past Instagram Feed**

```
string nextURL = instagramPagination.next_url;
Console.WriteLine (nextURL);
```

**The Actual Question**

How would I make it so that I can access this `Pagination` Variable from my getFeed method anywhere in this class?

Comment: If you load it asynchronously it won't be available until after you get your callback.

Comment: are you sure rootObject.pagination has a non-null value?

Comment: @Jason I have loaded it and so it is not a non-null value. i

Comment: @Jason I was able to print the value for next_url in the Console from the GetInstagramFeed method